# How to marge the TableLayout I got 3rows,3col, marge row1&2 and row2&3

Tags: c#, android, tablelayout, tablerow

***HELP*** 
I using TableLayout & TableRow, in the picture below I trying to marge No.4 and No.6 together just like No.1 however I had no idea how to do it. For no.1 I was able to do cause I just using Layout-weight to divide the screen into 3row,3col .

[image: Help1]

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="*">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
        <TextView
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1">
            <TableRow
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">
                <TextView
                    android:text="2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_span="2"
                    android:gravity="center" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3">
                <TextView
                    android:text="3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="4"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
        <TextView
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
        <TextView
            android:text="6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="right" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**below img is the result that i wants** 
[image]

Comment: can you post image layout what you want..?

Comment: I posted the layout that i want